# Deploy my app on Facebook.com

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, deployment, facebook-canvas

I have a question. If I develop my app locally using local server on my laptop, can I deploy it using canvas on facebook.com ? Then the users can login and access my app. Right? But if the server local wouldn't that make a problem. I am new to FB dev. so forgive me if this is not a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to host your code on your own server, or use the free hosting option Facebook provides via [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook)